# Who is Anonimous User

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I find this person appearing and doing edits, mostly turning them in to garbage.

Who is it ?

[image: anonim]

The latest sample (not so bad as previous ones), where your system actualy tells me it thinks this is a scam!
https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site allows people to perform some actions without logging in. Anonymous means a user that wasn't logged in made that action.

Comment: OK, next time I report it when inappropriate edit was made since I have no option to delete it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - if a bad edit was made, you can reverse it without reporting. Just explain why in the edit summary. Are you looking to change the ability of anonymous people to make edits or change the review process?

Comment: You are right, I can reverse it, and yes it would be nice to have the edit with credentials.

Comment: @bmike How is it that actions that require a certain level of reputation can be performed by users that aren't logged in?

Comment: @dwightk Anyone can suggest an edit that goes into a queue for others with review privs to review. The community moderation makes the edit stick if they approve it. Trusted users at some level can make reviews without needing another to review their edit if that's what you mean?

Comment: @bmike oh, I (incorrectly) thought edits took some minimum amount of rep to even suggest except on your own posts. Nevermind.

Comment: That's easy to test - open an incognito/private browsing window and you can see how anonymous edits and posts work.